# The Lebesgue covering dimension of the Cosmic String interval topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, physics, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry

Take the spacetime $(M,g)$ that satisfies Einstein's Field Equations exactly where $g$ is locally:

$$g= - c^2 dt^2 + d \rho^2 +  (\kappa^2 \rho^2 - a^2) d \phi^2 - 2 ac d\phi dt + dz^2 \ $$

in the cylindrical coordinate system where $z$ is called the axis of rotation. Where the $\kappa$ is the related to string tension and $a= c/\omega$ is inversely related to the angular frequency. Ostensibly this metric is not [strongly causal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_conditions) since it contains [CTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve) (closed timelike curve).

This metric is due to the rotating Cosmic String which is a particular type of topological defect that appears in the classical (topologically nontrivial) solutions in field theory, which in our case is a $U(1)$-Higgsed Yang-Mills in $3+1$ dimensions (flux tube stretched along its centre from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ on the $z$ axis, and rotating around the same axis).

The question:

What is the Lebesgue covering dimension of the interval topology induced by the Lorentzian metric $g$? Does this dimension change in the vicinity of the $z$ axis? In case is it a fractal, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for it to be so? Is it finite? What is the upper bound on its dimension?

The regimes of interest are:

- $0< \rho |\kappa| / a \ll 1 $
- $0< \rho  /a \ll |\kappa| \ll 1$
- $0< \rho  /a \ll 1 \ll |\kappa|$
- $0< |\kappa| \ll \rho /a \ll 1$

I'd be interested in an alalysis of the interval topology of the metric in this regimes.

I already know that this topology is "not locally Euclidean" and "non-Hausdorff".

---

PS:

Interval topology:

Take a time-oriented Lorentzian manifold that is weakly causal(aka not strongly causal), fix a point $p\in M$ and consider all (smooth) timelike future-directed curves through $p$ and denote by $L(\gamma)$ the Lorentzian length of $\gamma= \gamma(\xi)$, $\xi \in [a,b]$.
$$L(\gamma) = \int_a^b \sqrt{|g(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})|} d \xi$$
If $q \in M$ define the so called Lorentzian distance of $q$ from $p$ as
$$\tau(q,p) := \sup \{L(\gamma) \:|\: \mbox{$\gamma$ timelike future-directed from $p$ to $q$}\}$$
If no timelike future-directed from $p$ to $q$ exists, $\tau(q,p) :=0$.

Next define $I^+(p) := \{q \in M \:|\: \tau(q,p)>0\}$ and $I^-(p) := \{q \in M \:|\: \tau(p,q)>0\}$.

It is possible to prove that the family of sets $I(p,q):= I^+(p) \cap I^-(q)$ (with the suitable chronological order of the arguments) is a basis of the interval topology on $M$ which for weakly causal spacetimes is strictly coarser than the manifold topology $\tau_{\text{Manifold}}$.

Comment: Downvote without comment is irresponsible!